# filter_at not working with multiple columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am having trouble trying to use `filter_at` to filter outliers from multiple columns in my data (the last 9 columns to be precise, 50:58). I think that part of the problem is that I don't exactly understand how the `.vars_predicate` works.

When I try to filter multiple columns I usually get the following warnings:

> Error: `.vars_predicate` must be a call to `all_vars()` or `any_vars()`, not logical

or

> Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not logical

Here is the code that has worked for a single column [,50]:

```
data3  <- data2 %>%
      filter_at(abs(gaze_duration_n1_norm) <2.5)
```

Like I mentioned, I have 8 more columns that I would like to filter in this way. I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide a full working example of data and code (it can be mock-up data).

Comment: Does this work for you `filter_at(.tbl = data2 , .vars = 50:58, .vars_predicate = all_vars(abs(.) < 2.5 ))`?

Answer (score 1):

OP didn't provide example data but from the error messages one could guess that this might work

```
filter_at(.tbl = data2 , .vars = 50:58, .vars_predicate = all_vars(abs(.) < 2.5 ))
```

---

Reproducible example taken from `?filter_at`

```
# You can vary the selection of columns on which to apply the
# predicate. filter_at() takes a vars() specification:
filter_at(mtcars, vars(starts_with("d")), any_vars((. %% 2) == 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly fine now. I just still don't quite understand the arguments .vars() and .vars_predicate(), that's why I couldn't make the function work on my own.

Comment: Glad it helped. Made my comment an answer so this question can be regarded as solved (given you accept). Read through `?filter_at`; `.vars` a "...a numeric vector of column positions" and `.vars_predicate` "A quoted predicate expression as returned by `all_vars()` or `any_vars()`. For some background this might be worth reading: `vignette("programming")`

Comment: Great I will check it out. Yes, this question can be regarded as solved, thanks!